# Como posso alterar o estado de um item de array no React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

Eu tenho uma lista que é carrega após o retorno da api, essa lista popula um FlatList.
Ao clicar em algum item eu gostaria de marca-lo com o status que foi visualizado: **usuarioViu**

Como posso fazer a alteração somente do item clicado.

```html
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "codigoCondominio": "1212",
    "dataVencimento": "2018-03-10T00:00:00",
    "descricao": "Pagamento de taxa de licenciamento",
    "valor": 23900.9,
    "flagBloqueio": false,
    "dataBloqueio": null,
    "idUsuarioConcordou": null,
    "createTime": "2018-03-23T01:35:29.957",
    "arquivado": false,
    "dataPagamento": null,
    "numeroLancamento": 0,
    "codigo": "1212",
    "nome": "Edificio 0001",
    "usuarioViu": null,
    "flagVisualizado": null,
    "vencido": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "codigoCondominio": "1212",
    "dataVencimento": "2018-03-10T00:00:00",
    "descricao": "Pacto administradora",
    "valor": 45000,
    "flagBloqueio": true,
    "dataBloqueio": null,
    "idUsuarioConcordou": null,
    "createTime": "2018-03-23T01:36:06.52",
    "arquivado": false,
    "dataPagamento": null,
    "numeroLancamento": 0,
    "codigo": "1212",
    "nome": "Edificio 0002",
    "usuarioViu": null,
    "flagVisualizado": null,
    "vencido": true
  }
]
```

Simplificando eu gostaria de alterar o primeiro objeto [0].usuarioViu = true

Estou trabalhando com React-native, Redux-saga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que utilizar [`TouchableHighlight`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html) para que os items respondam adequadamente aos toques.

1. Defina um método para atualizar o valor da propriedade.

   ```
   handleUsuarioViu = (index) => {
     let dados = this.state.dados;
     alert(dados[index].usuarioViu); // Apenas para demonstrar
     dados[index].usuarioViu = true;
     this.setState({ dados: dados });
   };
   ```

   O alerta é apenas para demonstrar o funcionamento, a cada toque/clique, irá exibir o valor atual. Depois é atualizado o valor da propriedade `usuarioViu` do item que recebeu o toque/clique.
2. Na propriedade `renderItem` de `FlatList` altere para:

   ```
   <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handleUsuarioViu(index)}>
     <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
   ```

> Você pode ver funcionando em [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/BJ226j4cM)

Comment: Valeu mesmo, resolveu meu problema.